# Can I interact with this creature?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

I encountered this creature a couple of times while playing Super Mario Galaxy, but could never get close to it:
[image: What is this creature?]

So far, I haven't been able to find any information in any walkthroughs, and I'm not sure what it's called, so my searches have come up blank.

Is it possible to catch this creature?
If it is possible, what happens when you do catch it?

Comment: PS. Sorry for the bad quality screenshot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oh, this is a fun little guy. He is, in fact, an enemy, so yes, he is interact-able. If you manage to chase this bugger down (running long jumps help here) and spin/stomp him, he will explode in a shower of ~20 star bits.

They're called "[Starbags](http://www.mariowiki.com/Starbag)" according to Super Mario Wiki.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to see if I can catch it now. Although, I'm not entirely sure it's worth it just for a few star bits, but I will do it just to prove that I can get the better of him/her :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can catch it, it's not particularly easy and it's been a long time since I've played so can't offer any specific advice.

I believe they drop a *lot* of star bits when you land a successful hit.

I don't know what it's called.

Again, it's been a while since I last played so apologies for being vague -- this will hopefully help until a fuller answer appears.)

Comment: Excellent. Well at least I know now that it is possible, and I'm not just wasting time trying.

Comment: @jaminja IIRC they walk under the sand, yes? So try to shepherd them to the edge or corner of the sand so they can't escape as easily.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, this creature is invisible, and become visible only when it stops. But, you can see its footsteps in the sand. My technique to catch it is to follow its trail when it is invisible, to make a long jump when he appears to stop, and to make a spin attack when landing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard to beat this guy. Just stand still, and he will come to a stop and appear. Immediately run toward him, and when you're almost to where he was standing, do a spin. **You can still hit him for a split second after he turns invisible.** The timing is a little tricky, but it shouldn't take you too many tries to get him. It helps if you're standing uphill from him when you both stop.